# Query using LIke Clause

Tags: soql

I am trying to display the information based on the user input value. Below is my complete code

```
public class CallCentre {
    public String search { get; set; }
    public String searchquery { get; set; }
    public list <Contact> con{get;set;}
    public list<contact> contact{get;set;}
    public string searchstring {get;set;}

    public void search() {
        string query = 'SELECT Name, New_Email__c,Account.Property_Owner__c, 
        New_Mobile_Phone__c, Unit1__r.Name, Email, Phone, tenant_street__c, 
        tenant_city__c, Tenant_ID__c from Contact 
        where (Tenant_Status__c = \'Current\') AND (Tenant_Street__c 
        like \'%%'+search+'%%\' OR Tenant_Street__c like \'%%-'+search+'%-%\'  OR  
        Tenant_ID__c like \'%'+search+'%\') LIMIT 15';

        con = Database.query(query);
        system.debug('Con List'+con.size()+con);
    }

    public void clear() {
        con.clear();
    }

    public CallCentre() {
    }
}
```

Query is working perfect. But here I want my users to skip the special characters
Ex: If I input 182-A,182 It is pulling  the similar data but If I input     182 A(Skipping special characters).

My Query is  not populating result. I want the result should be same if the user input 182 or 182-A or 182 A. Any help  would be Great.

Comment: would you mind sharing it wha tyou have attempted so far to do so?

Comment: Thank you glls, for your response. I am new to development , changing conditions in the like clause(like \'%%'+search+'%%\') will help my situation. I have tried to give a space between wild cards. And followed some of the developer suggestions but  still no luck .

Comment: Rajesh, if the solutions that have been posted aren't helping, it would be useful if you can share *why*. Are you finding errors? If so, please include the entire error text. Your code doesn't look like you've acted on any of these suggestions. (I've also formatted your code to be more readable - please make sure to use the `{}` code formatting button).

Answer (score 2):

SOQL does not inherently support that kind of "fuzzy" matching.

While it's possible that [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm#sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples) might be a better match for your needs, if we continue down the SOQL path, you'd need to do some filtration in Apex on your search terms before passing them to the query engine. You can't achieve what you're looking for just by changing your SOQL query.

It sounds like what you want to do is treat all non-alphanumeric characters as wild cards. One way you could attack this is to use a regular expression to identify and replace those characters with a single `%` character, the SOQL wildcard. That might look something like this:

```
String cleanedSearchTerm = searchTerm.replaceAll(
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '%');
```

The regular expression uses a negated character class to match any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters and substitutes in a wild card. This would transform your examples `"182-A"` and `"182 A"` into the same search term, `"182%A"`. Note that this would *not* produce the same result for `"182"`, as that seems to be a materially different search.

That said, you can elaborate on this example to use regular expressions to transform your search terms more extensively if needed.

Comment: David Thank you for your response, I tried it but failed, May be I am not addressing in proper way. Below is my code

Comment: Rajesh, please do not post code in comment threads - it's impossible to read. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

New Answer:

The replaceAll method is actually more suitable as you're looking to eliminate possible spaces in your input value. In the sample code below, it replaces all possible spaces with "-". So "182 A" would become "182-A".

```
String search = '182 A';
search = search.replaceAll("\\s+","-");
```

Old Answer:

You can trim the input value first before you proceed to use it in your query.

```
String search = '182 A';
search = search.trim();
```

Comment: `String.trim()` removes [trailing and leading whitespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm). It doesn't filter non-alphanumeric characters, as Rajesh seems to want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out David! Appreciate your comment! Thought String.trim() would have done the trick for this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  still no luck with code

Comment: Just updated my answer. As David Reed said, it's not advisable that you do the matching as part of your soql query. Because it makes it harder to understand your soql query and to make modification to it later on. It's better to separate the matching logic by using apex code instead.

Answer (score 0):

What are the special chars that you wants to remove is upto you and the business logic you are trying to implement.

The method you are looking or is [replace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) or its other variants. For ex.,

```
String value = value.replace('-', '%');
```

You would need to do this for all chars that you want to ignore and use the final value in your like predicate.